# ActiveRecord finding only hourly records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I've got a table with a datetime column that has records for every minute (logging data every minute)

I want to get only the records that occurred at the top of the hour(1pm, 2pm, 3pm, 4pm, etc).

What would be the best way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`extract`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) to find the values which have zero for the minutes:

```
top_of_the_hours = Model.where('extract(minute from your_datetime) = 0')
```

That will also work with PostgreSQL but you'd need to switch to `strftime` for SQLite.